# Constructing a partition of a nested family of sets that is closed under unions and nonempty intersections.

Tags: set-theory, set-partition

I have some set theory background, but neither topology nor functional analysis are fields where I feel comfortable, so this may be a very simple question to people familiar with those fields, but I'm stumped. Those considerations have popped up in my thesis, which covers topics from philosophical logic.

I have simplified the question since first posting it.

Let $U_x$ be a subset of $\mathcal P(S)$ such that $x \in \cap U_x$: with the following properties:

$(1)\,\,\,U_x$ is nested: for all $X,Y \in U_x$ either $X \subseteq Y$ or $Y \subseteq X$.

$(2)\,\,\,U_x$ is closed under unions

$(3)\,\,\,U_x$ is closed under non-empty intersections

**Question:**
(I have refined my question, after receiving feedback that it's not clear enough.)

My question is whether from the properties of $U_x$ alone we can easily derive a particular type of partition of $S$?

The kind of partition I have in mind can be exemplified on the assumption that $S$ is finite. If $S$ is finite then we can order its elements by natural numbers. So there exists an $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $U_x=\{X^0, X^1,...,X^n\}$ has the following form: $X^0 \subseteq X^1 \subseteq... \subseteq X^{n-1} \subseteq X^n$. This allows for the definition of the following equivalence relation on $S$: $\; y \sim_x z \;$ iff $\; \{y,z\}\subseteq X^{k-1}\setminus X^k$ for some $ 0\lt k\le n$. And the set $S/\sim_x$ is a partition of $S$.

Can this kind of partition always be achieved for any $S$ and $U_x$ as defined, or would some additional assumptions need to be made? By this *kind* I mean *all* elements of $U_x$ contributing in an orderly manner as in the given example.

What if we additionally say that:

$(4)\,\,\,$ There are no infinitely descending $\subseteq$-sequences, $...\subseteq Y\subseteq X$ of smaller and smaller $\qquad X,Y,... \in U_x$? That is, the ordering of all $X \in U_x$ by set inclusion is a well-ordering.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: (1) By $F_x$, do you mean $F(x)$, where $x \in S$?  Assuming so, (2) When you say "My question is whether it can be shown that each $Fx$ induces a partition on $S$..", in what way does an element of $P(S)$ "induce a partition". And if you're asking this for each individual $x$, how does the function $F$ enter into things? Why not ask, "Suppose I have a subset $U$ of $P(S)$ with these four properties; does $U$ induce a partition?"

Comment: When you say "guarantee a partition" what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Yes, by$F_x$ I mean $F(x)$ s.t. $x \in S$. But $F_x$ is not an element of $P(S)$ but an element of $P(P(S))$ (there was a typo in the definition of $F$) with properties (1)-(4). Let me give an example of what I have in mind: suppose $S$ is finite, so for each $F_x$ there exists a natural number $n$ s.t $F_x$ has the structure: $X^0 \subseteq X^1 \subseteq ... X^{n-1} \subseteq X^n$. Given this structure of $F_x$ we can define an equivalence relation on $S$ as follows: $y \sim_x z$ iff $ \{y,z \} \subseteq X^k \setminus X^{k-1}$, and the set of $\sim_x$-equivalence classes partitions $S$.

Comment: @JohnHughes You're correct about the simpler formulation of the question. I'll edit that.

Comment: @NotMike By guarantee, I mean that there is some obvious/natural way of defining a partition of $S$ from the properties of $F_x$. Does my example from the comment above help in clarifying what I mean?

Comment: @JohnHughes Can I always define an equivalence relation like in the example I gave in an earlier comment (for finite $S$), even when $S$ is uncountable? That is, are the properties of $U_x$ sufficient to define such an equivalence relation, which then can be used to partition $S$. This is the kind of partition I had in mind.

Comment: Then you should ask that question as a new question. But before you do, you should get rid of "like in the example", because "like" is too vague, and anyone who answers will rapidly get involved in a chameleon question like this one has become. [Have you noticed that no one else has jumped in to answer? That's because they're all wiser than I am.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with this question is that the answer is "yes", but stupidly so:

> "My question is whether from the properties of $U_x$ alone we can easily derive a partition of $S$?"

Yes. In many ways:

1. Partition $S$ into singletons.
2. Partition $S$ into a single subset, $S$.
3. Partition $S$ into $S-\{x\}$ and $\{x\}$.

(any of these partitions might be identical, depending on the set $S$).

The first two use properties of $U_x$ vacuously; the third uses the property that $S$ is nonempty, because $x$ must be an element of $S$.

I think that you really need to try harder to formulate the question you want to ask (as both my and @Not Mike's comments suggested). The part where you can't quite say what exactly you mean? That's the *hard* one, and we can't help, because we don't know what you mean either. :)